# How to run / execute input cells in Databricks Python Notebook

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I written the following code in Databricks notebook

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
age = input("How old are you, {0}?".format(name))
print(age)
```

As you guessed, after running the cell I am asked to 'Please enter your name:' The problem is I don't where to make the entry. If this was written in intelliJ IDEA or IDLE I would be given a separate window to enter my name. However, with Databricks notebook, even if I enter the answer in a different cell it appears to be constantly waiting for an input, see image:

[image: where to enter]

I really should know the answer to this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
dbutils.widgets.text("name", "Please enter your name")
dbutils.widgets.text("age", "How old are you?")
```

Look at the top of your notebook and you will look the textboxes to fill, fill it and execute another cell with this commands

```
name = dbutils.widgets.get("name")
print(name)
age = dbutils.widgets.get("age")
print(age)
```

Doc link https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/notebooks/widgets.html#widget-types

Comment: thanks. I feared that was the answer. I just learning Python so I will train on intelliJ IDEA. Thanks again Fabio

Comment: I tried making the 'age' from an text into an integer by changing the code as follows: `dbutils.widgets.int("age", "How old are you?")`, \n but Databricks doesn't recognize the 'int'. Is there a way of changing to integer?

Comment: I figured it out ... `age = int(dbutils.widgets.get("age"))`

Answer (score 11):

The `input` function is now natively supported in Databricks for DBR 11.2+.

An example notebook showing the use of `input` with `pdb` is available here:
https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/python-debugger.html

A short screencast showing the execution of your example:
[image]