# input type function in Databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I have a script that requires a user's input in Jupyter. The script is similar to the famous [tic tac toe python game](https://dev.to/jamesshah/the-classic-tictactoe-game-in-python-cpi), where a user inputs a location on the board, the script waits for an input and continues. Unfortunately, DataBricks doesn't seem to have `input()`, but it does have [widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html). However, widgets don't seem to wait for input and therefore, my script fails. Is there a way to use widgets in DataBricks and have my script wait for user input before proceeding, like `input()`?

For example,

```
for i in range(2):
  name = input("Enter name: ")
  print(f"Name is {name}")
```

results in a loop that waits for user input.

The equivalent in DataBricks should be

```
for i in range(2):
  dbutils.widgets.text("name", "")
  name = dbutils.widgets.get("name")
  print(f"Name is {name}")
```

results in

```
Name is
Name is
```

because the loop never pauses to allow user input.

Comment: Unfortunately, widgets don't work that way. But maybe you can implement a workaround of sorts. Check the official documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#configure-widget-settings-1)

Comment: Also, you've put the widget creation command inside the loop. Usually, that's not what we want to be doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run / execute input cells in Databricks Python Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117964/how-to-run-execute-input-cells-in-databricks-python-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for newer readers, as [Bob Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62642453/input-type-function-in-databricks#comment131533021_62642453) mentioned in a comment, Databricks in fact does support Python's `input()` function as a native feature in DBR 11.2+

This is answered by [How to run / execute input cells in Databricks Python Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117964/how-to-run-execute-input-cells-in-databricks-python-notebook)

[image]