# How to give input to prompt asked in cells in Databricks Notebook?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

As you can see the library I'm using is asking to make an entry but there's no box/window where I can make the entry. How do I make an entry here amongst y/n/u/f?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run / execute input cells in Databricks Python Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117964/how-to-run-execute-input-cells-in-databricks-python-notebook)

Comment: No it doesn't @BobSmith